# Put PHP code in PHP if set

Tags: php, html

im working on php page where for call contend in same page i've added

```
<?php if (isset($cpID)) {   echo ' '; }
```

i've added in the two '' some code that work nice, but have small troubles with this code:

```
onClick="location.href='waiting.php?picID='.$cpID.''"
```

it's give me syntax error and i not know how place it in the PHP if set, please can help me? Thanks Stew

**COMPLETE CODE:**

```
<?php
if (isset($cpID)) {
    echo '</p><button class="btn btn-large btn-block btn-success" onClick="location.href='waiting.php?picID='.$cpID.''"  type="button">Click here to upload this Cover to your Facebook Profile</button></p>';
}
?>
```

Comment: You didn't close the string after the single quote.

Comment: @Stew, Post more code, lines above and below maybe.

Comment: @Cthulhu where i can post complete code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Problem:

```
echo '
</p><button class="btn btn-large btn-block btn-success" onClick="location.href='waiting.php?picID='.$cpID.''"  type="button">Click here to upload this Cover to your Facebook Profile</button></p>
';
}
```

The problem is that your single quote for the **echo** is being closed by the one next to `location.href='` You need to escape your single quotes.

---

#### Solution:

```
echo '
</p><button class="btn btn-large btn-block btn-success" onClick="location.href=\'waiting.php?picID='.$cpID.'\'"  type="button">Click here to upload this Cover to your Facebook Profile</button></p>
';
```

Please notice, I have **escaped** the single quotes with `\'`

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have an issue with too many " and ' quotes. There are some things you can do.
I am sure that I understand your code correctly, but you can try:

```
$myEcho = (isset($cpID)) ? "" : "location.href='waiting.php?picID=$cpID'";
echo $myEcho;
```

I did it not try now myself, so I hope I did not add a syntax error by typo now :=)

If it does not work, please post a few more details about the error you get.

Comment: i need add it in button action and not in php

Comment: @Stew Your issue was that you weren't escaping your singlequotes, making your string close pre-maturely. Escape your `'` within the PHP string as `\'`

Answer (score 0):

Try not setting your picId as a var then try this. If it is in a form input label it as id="picID"

echo "onclick='location.href=waiting.php?picID="+document.getElementById('picID').value, true);
<>

Answer (score 0):

I think the first problem was that the PHP tags were not in place. I think this should work

```
<?php
if (isset($cpID)) {
$cpID = $cpID.' ';
echo '
</p><button class="btn btn-large btn-block btn-success" onClick="location.href='waiting.php?picID='.$cpID.'"  type="button">Click here to upload this Cover to your Facebook Profile</button></p>
';
}
?>
```